# Leave only Nth text between two marker strings

Tags: perl

I am working on Mac os and am looking for the most elegant solution for the below problem. Since it purely text related I thought perl would be the best choice?

- I have a data file on disk eg data.html (does not matter its html)
- It contains Chinese characters (so file is utf8 encoded I believe)
- Its structure is like this:

  ```
  Some top text
  Some too text
  Some top styles text
  <h1>Topic 1 text</h1>
  Some text that is applicable to topic 1 with formatting...
  <h1>Topic 2 title</h1>
  Some text applicable to topic 2...
  ```

I want to write a file for each topic that contains the top text and styles. So input os data.html output is topic1.html, topic2.html...

Comment: Definitely doable, but without details, it's hard to say more.

Comment: If you need to extract data from a HTML file, you should probably use a dedicated parser, see http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/02/parsing-html-with-perl-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file is really that simple and doesn't have any other h1 tags, this probably should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :encoding(utf8));

open my $input, '<', 'data.html';
my $content = join '', <$input>;
close $input;

my @parts = split /<\/?h1>/, $content;
my $top_text_and_styles = shift @parts;
my $count = 0;
while (my ($topic, $body) = splice @parts, 0, 2) {
    my $topic_content = join "", $top_text_and_styles, $topic, $body;
    $count += 1;
    my $output_name = "topic${count}.html";
    open my $output, '>', $output_name;
    print $output $topic_content;
    close $output;
}
```

Comment: thanks currently travelling but will try this and build further on it!